# MapBox Map integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mapbox, apple-maps

I am new to map box and I want to have a customised map for my application, I have gone through all the guides of mapBox provided online but they seems to be a bit confusing , I have two things over there,

1. Create a map using MapBox studio
2. Integrate a map in your ios application

I just want to know that if I create a map using MapBox studio can I use the same map for my application, plus will the default mapKit API will also work in the same project.

Will the delegate functions of mapKit API works for the mapBox and most importantly, how I can do all the things I am not able to find a example code.

If anyone can provide me with the some example code in which they have integrated a map using mapBox will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible for you to use Mapbox GL to use and integrate in your app. and the delegates for Mapbox GL are provided in their sites and their API will also work for sure, so don't worry give it a try, to have  a reference about the example on MapboxGL go to this sites

[Mapbox GL example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-example)

[official site](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/)